# iOS 7 UItableview cell background view

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios7

I am using a image view as tableview cell background view. When I am compiling my source in xcode 4.x, it works fine i.e, In both iOS 6.x and 7.0 it  is working fine. But when I compile my source in xcode 5.0, the background image view is not appearing iOS 7.

Any idea, why it is not working? is there any restrictions on uitableview cell background view in iOS 7?

```
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:accountProfileTypeCell];
    UIImageView *cellBgView =[[UIImageView alloc]init];
    [cellBgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cellBgView.png"]];
    [cell setBackgroundView:cellBgView];
}
```

Comment: how are you setting the background? Show the actual code you are using.

Comment: [UIImage imageImaged: ] imageImaged is not any method in UIImage Class. Its - imageNamed. please edit it in your code

Comment: sorry I made this mistake while pasting this code, but I wrote the code correctly in xcode

Comment: can you try adding : cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

Comment: The only thing missing is setting frame to cellBgView. Setting image will not resize imageView.

Comment: welcome my friend.. i have added it as an answer. please accept it so other can benefit from it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try adding : cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

Answer (score 2):

You must set the background in willDisplayCell. The below code is same as yours only thing is that move it in willDisplay method

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    if(cell.backgroundView==nil){
        UIImageView *cellBgView =[[UIImageView alloc]init];
        [cellBgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cellBgView.png"]];
        [cell setBackgroundView:cellBgView];
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not required that we must do it only in will display cell method, we can do it in cellforrow method itself, the mistake I made was not setting tableview cell color to clear color

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It's work for me

```
 cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:accountProfileTypeCell];
UIView *cellBgView =[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, [cell frame].size.width, [cell frame].size.height)];
[cellBgView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cellBgView.png"]]];
[cell setBackgroundView:cellBgView];
```

Comment: `VActivityStreamBack`?

Comment: VActivityStreamBack ?? May I know what is this? Thanks

Comment: I have copied this code from one of my app where it was "VActivityStreamBack" and unfortunately I miss that to replace. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing missing is setting frame to cellBgView. Setting image to it will not resize imageView. However if you initialize imageView with initWithImage: , it will resize imageView to fit the image.

Comment: I think, we don't need to set frame for background views.Thanks

Comment: Yes, if you use backgroundView initialized by cell & not the one you have initialized.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to apply autosizing in your imageview.

If your imageview is applied to an entire screen.  Assign all margins to it.

Checkout the image

[image: Set Autosizing your view in order to make it compatible with both iOS6 & iOS7]